# Deactivate angular2-draggable for children

Tags: javascript, angular

I am looking for a solution or workaround to disable the ngDraggable directives for children of the draggable component.

I have a chat window and want it only to be draggable on the header of it and not for the rest of the chat.

```
<div class="position-absolute shadow-sm d-flex flex-column chat-window"
     style="z-index: 999; width:500px; height: 400px;"
     [inBounds]="inBounds"
     ngDraggable
     ngResizable
     [rzMinWidth]="300"
     [rzMinHeight]="250"
     [position]="position">
  <app-chat-tab-desktop-header [chatTab]="chatTab"></app-chat-tab-desktop-header>
  <app-chat-tab class="d-flex flex-grow-1" (click)="$event.stopPropagation();$event.preventDefault()"  [chatTab]="chatTab"></app-chat-tab>
</div>
```

I tried to use `(click)="$event.stopPropagation();$event.preventDefault()"` but it had no effect.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with `(mousedown)` event instead. It should work.